# Html 5 vs other technologies

Tags: html

I have been reading a lot of stuff about HTML 5 recently. Something still looks very fuzzy to me and I hope somebody can help me understand it better.

Is HTML 5 for the "technology" to create the UI only? If I need to create an application to access bank accounts, how is it possible that HTML 5 will replace all other technologies? I mean there must be some kind of web service that the application has to use to access the data on the server and I can't see how that piece can be done with HTML 5.

Comment: You might want to skip over to HTML5 doctor and catch up on the new tags. HTML5 is a great upgrade over straight HTML http://html5doctor.com/ .  There are several other places such at nettuts

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 is indeed markup and JavaScript APIs for the browser.  It isn't intended to access data on servers.

But it's rarely used on its own.

CSS adds style to content.

JavaScript makes client side code dynamic.

AJAX allows you to make asynchronous calls to services to get data, keeping your UI responsive.

Yes, you still need services.

HTML 5 replaces earlier versions of HTML, nothing more.

Comment: Also, I think we can add the javascript "APIs" for the canvas, drag and drop, and others to the definition of HTML5, even if it's not part of the markup. But, for sure, in order to get a complete web application, at some point there is some server code involved.

Comment: HTML5 is a lot more than just markup for the browser.  It also consists of a lot of javascript interfaces to methods, properties and objects.

Answer (score 2):

As with any new technology there is always a lot of speculation from commentators who don't really understand it... It always made me chuckle when I heard people talking about sites being 'Web 2.0' or 'Ajaxy'

Put simply:

HTML5 is just the same old html which we've been using since the nineties but with some improvements from HTML4&XHTML1. There are a few new tags, some of which aren't even new they've just been standardised.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 provides native support for many features that used to be possible only with plugins or complex hacks (a native drawing API, native sockets, and so on). Plugins, of course, present problems:

- Plugins cannot always be installed.
- Plugins can be disabled or blocked (for example, the Apple iPad does not ship with a Flash plugin).
- Plugins are a separate attack vector.
- Plugins are difficult to integrate with the rest of an HTML document (because of plugin boundaries, clipping, and transparency issues).

Although some plugins have high install rates, they are often blocked in controlled corporate environments. In addition, some users choose to disable these plugins due to the unwelcome advertising displays that they empower. However, if users disable your plugin, they also disable the very program you’re relying on to display your content.

This is where HTML5 comes on the scene, smiles, and waves its magic wand of native functionality. You can style elements with CSS and script with JavaScript. In fact, this is where HTML5 flexes its biggest muscle, showing us a power that just didn’t exist in previous versions of HTML. ***It’s not just that the new elements provide new functionality. It’s also the added native interaction with scripting and styling that enables us to do much more than we could ever do before.***

Take the new canvas element, for example. It enables us to do some pretty fundamental things that were not possible before (try drawing a diagonal line in a web page in HTML4). However, what’s most interesting is the power that we can unlock with the APIs and the styling we can apply with just a few lines of CSS code. Like well-behaved children, the HTML5 elements also play nicely together. For example, you can grab a frame from a video element and display it on a canvas, and the user can just click the canvas to play back the video from the frame you just grabbed. This is just one example of what a native code has to offer over a plugin. In fact, virtually everything becomes easier when you’re not working with a black box. What this all adds up to is a truly powerful new medium.